# append query in SQL not working right

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

**INSERT INTO** Table2 ( Customer, Order_Date, Stamp_Date, Travelled_Distance, Units, Country, Comments )

**SELECT**

```
'CustomerFamily' As Customer, 
T1.Order_Date AS Order_Date, 
T1.Stamp_Date AS Stamp_Date, 
T1.Travelled_Distance-T2.Travelled_Distance AS Travelled_Distance, 
T1.Units AS Units, 
'Canada' AS Country, 
'' AS Comments
```

**FROM**

```
Table1 AS T1, 
Table1 AS T2
```

**WHERE**

```
T1.Customer='Jake' And 
T2.Customer='Mike' And 
T2.Order_Date=T1.Order_Date
```

**ORDER BY**

```
T1.Order_Date;
```

This is my append query that has a calculation in it ( for the days that jake and mike travel on same day it subtracts mikes travel distance from jakes)

the **PROBLEM** is that it does all the calculation fine and puts it into Table 2 but there is two rows which are the same for every single calculation.

why is it repeating twice? I can't spot the error

Comment: Is there any date in `Table1` where Mike or Jake has travelled more than once in the same date?

Comment: yep lol thanks ypercube. the problem has been fixed

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you're using implicit joins instead of explicit?

Comment: jsut because when i tried them a few times before it kept giving me a JOIN format nto supported..or function nto supported or somethign not supported i dont quite remember

Comment: If there is any date in Table1 where someone has travelled more than once in the same date, then you should not use `DISTINCT` but `GROUP BY` and `SUM(Travelled_Distance)`

Comment: actually sry nevermind they dont travel more than once on the same day. that is very helpful for future reference tho thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'CustomerFamily' As Customer, 
T1.Order_Date AS Order_Date, 
T1.Stamp_Date AS Stamp_Date, 
T1.Travelled_Distance-T2.Travelled_Distance AS Travelled_Distance, 
T1.Units AS Units, 
'Canada' AS Country, 
'' AS Comments
```